# "The C compiler "/usr/bin/cc" is not able to compile a simple test program."

Tags: c, eclipse, cygwin, clion

I installed Cygwin64 and everything is fine in Toolchains [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7yLY.png), even the C Compiler is ticked. But I get these errors whenever I create a new project and 'Run' and 'Debug' buttons are grayed-out from the get go;

```
Error:The C compiler "/usr/bin/cc" is not able to compile a simple test program.
It fails with the following output:
Change Dir: /cygdrive/c/Users/J/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/untitled132-5df26809/5df26809/__default__/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make.exe" "cmTC_7ca0a/fast"
C:/cygwin64/bin/make.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygguile-17.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.

Error:Configuration Debug
The C compiler "/usr/bin/cc" is not able to compile a simple test program.
It fails with the following output:
Change Dir: /cygdrive/c/Users/J/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/untitled132-5df26809/5df26809/Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make.exe" "cmTC_7db24/fast"
C:/cygwin64/bin/make.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygguile-17.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.

Error:Configuration Release
The C compiler "/usr/bin/cc" is not able to compile a simple test program.
It fails with the following output:
Change Dir: /cygdrive/c/Users/J/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/untitled132-5df26809/5df26809/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make.exe" "cmTC_fe477/fast"
C:/cygwin64/bin/make.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygguile-17.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.

Error:Configuration RelWithDebInfo
The C compiler "/usr/bin/cc" is not able to compile a simple test program.
It fails with the following output:
Change Dir: /cygdrive/c/Users/J/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/untitled132-5df26809/5df26809/RelWithDebInfo/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make.exe" "cmTC_c2ddb/fast"
C:/cygwin64/bin/make.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygguile-17.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.

Error:Configuration MinSizeRel
The C compiler "/usr/bin/cc" is not able to compile a simple test program.
It fails with the following output:
Change Dir: /cygdrive/c/Users/J/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/untitled132-5df26809/5df26809/MinSizeRel/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make.exe" "cmTC_827b4/fast"
C:/cygwin64/bin/make.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygguile-17.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
```

Comment: I think `cygguile-17.dll` isn't in your windows path environment variable.

Comment: where can I have it?

Comment: Its probably: `C:/cygwin64/bin` Take a look in explorer. Then make sure that you have that in your windows environment variable PATH.

Comment: I don't have it. Is it something downloadable from cygwin?

Comment: I don't have in my entire system. So where to get it?

Comment: I think you want to update cygwin.

Comment: I actually downloaded all devel category from cygwin. What can I miss?

Answer (score 0):

cygguile-17.dll belongs to libguile17 package. Reistall it.

Use https://cygwin.com/packages/ for this type of search